# how to find if the next n or more rows are lesser or equal to a given value for columns of a dataframe?(pandas, python)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, transformation

Problem datasets:

```
datasetA = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1,100,80,10,8,8,9,11],
                              'B':[1,100,90,12,7,8,9,10],
                              'C':[1,100,80,13,12,11,12,13],
                              'D':[1,100,90,9,8,7,10,10]}
                              'E':[1,100,90,19,18,17,9,10]})
     A    B    C    D   E
0    1    1    1    1   1
1  100  100  100  100 100
2   80   90   80   90  80
3   10   12   13    9  19
4    8    7   12    8  18
5    8    8   11    7  17
6    9    9   12   10   9
7   11   10   13   10  10
```

the number we need to check values against is 10
if in a column we reach values less or equal than 10 for four or more consecutive rows we fetch that number which first fell to =<10 in those rows. if the number rises later on above 10 then we fetch a Zero.

Expected output:

```
A B C D E
0 7 0 9 0
```

please keep in mind i have 7million plus columns i need to calulate this for

Comment: What's exactly your question? Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: sure, im trying to get the first value that falls to 10 or below and stays =<10 for about 4 or more rows continuously.if the value never falls to below or equal to 10 or eventually rises above 10 later on in the column i want to fetch a zero

Comment: the first column should return 10.. no?

Comment: no because in the end it went to 11(above 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def set_column_value(column):
    value_to_be_set = 0
    consecutive_less_than_10_counter = 0
    for index, val in enumerate(column):
        if column[index] <= 10:
            consecutive_less_than_10_counter += 1
        else:
            consecutive_less_than_10_counter = 0

        if consecutive_less_than_10_counter == 4:
            value_to_be_set = val
            break
    column = [value_to_be_set for i in column]
    return column


df = df.apply(lambda column: set_column_value(column))
# this will use axis=0 i.e iterate through each column!
```

Comment: for about 7 million columns wont that take like forever?

Comment: your use-case requires you to check consecutive values (so you cant sort it), and you haven't shared any other property that applies to the dataframe, so it looks like you need to check each value;
You can always split the dataframe into smaller dataframes by column since your columns are not inter-dependent

Comment: I have tested it before sharing the answer- perhaps you are expecting your result in (1x n_columns) size while this code returns (n_rows x n_columns) size, if so just use df.head(1) since all rows are duplicate

Comment: if consecutive_less_than_10_counter == 4: (end of line) 
            value_to_be_set = column[index-3] (end of line) 
        if column[index]>10: (end of line) 
            value_to_be_set = 0 (end of line) 
    column = [value_to_be_set for i in column] (end of line) 
    return column (end of line)

Answer (score 1):

Using a the pandas DataFrame `rolling` method with a custom function:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1,100,80,10,8,8,9,11],
                        'B':[1,100,90,12,7,8,9,10],
                        'C':[1,100,80,13,12,11,12,13],
                        'D':[1,100,90,9,8,7,10,10]})
dfr = df.rolling(window=4).agg(lambda w: (w<=10).all())
dfr.dropna(inplace=True)

lst=[]
for c in list(df):
    try:
        #Retrieve first index we have a four consecutive numbers less than 10
        first_id = dfr.index[dfr[c] == 1].values.tolist()[0]
        # Consider the product of all 0s or 1s we have after
        v = dfr.loc[first_id:][c].prod()

        #Append  column, first index if all ones
        if v == 1:
            lst.append((c, df.loc[first_id-3][c]))
        # Otherwise append columns, 0
        else: 
            lst.append((c, 0))

    except:
        lst.append((c,0))

lst
[('A', 0), ('B', 7), ('C', 0), ('D', 9)]
```

Comment: You only need to find the first 10 after the index this module retrieves

Comment: yeah but it shouldnt say ('D',6) D should be 9

Comment: I though you were looking for the index of first occurrence, edited the answer to return the value

Comment: i tried it again still didnt work could you please check once more

Comment: Try now, I am getting the same result you wrote above